# ä/ü/... are not displayed when including via get_template_part()

Tags: get-template-part

I just have the problem that characters like ä and ü appear as question marks when I include something via get_template_part().

Does anyone know what this could be? Everywhere else the letters are displayed correctly.

Comment: That's normally a character set conversion problem. What environment are you running in? Is there a chance you have a version of PHP that doesn't support UTF-8 (or UTF-16 if you're on Windows)? Do you have any plugins or hooks that might be processing the content and breaking it?